# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, program-entry-point, inputmismatchexception

I need help with one exercise in java, I'm stuck on this error for 2 hours maybe. Any help would be great.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at prodavnica.Prodavnica.main(Prodavnica.java:60)
Java Result: 1
```

---

```
package prodavnica;

public class Proizvod {
    
    private String ime_proizvod;
    private static int cena;

    public Proizvod(String ime_proizvod, int cena) {
        this.ime_proizvod = ime_proizvod;
        this.cena=cena;
    }

    public String getIme_proizvod() {
        return ime_proizvod;
    }

    public void setIme_proizvod(String ime_proizvod) {
        this.ime_proizvod = ime_proizvod;
    }

    public static int getCena() {
        return cena;
    }

    public static void setCena(int cena) {
        Proizvod.cena = cena;
    }
    
    public void pecatiPodatoci(){
        System.out.println("Ime: "+ime_proizvod+" Cena: "+cena);
    }
    
}
```

AND:

```
package prodavnica;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prodavnica {

    private String ime_prodavnica;
    private Proizvod proizvodi[]=new Proizvod[20];

    public Prodavnica(String ime_prodavnica) {
        this.ime_prodavnica = ime_prodavnica;
    }
    
    int br=0;
    
    public void dodadiProizvod(Proizvod p){
        proizvodi[br]=p;
        br++;
    }
    
      public Proizvod najskapProizvod(){
        
        Proizvod max=proizvodi[0];
        
        for(int r=0;r<proizvodi.length;r++){
            
            if(max.getCena()<proizvodi[r+1].getCena()){
                max=proizvodi[r+1];
            }
        }
        return max;
        
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        Prodavnica pro1=new Prodavnica("Tinex");
        
        int n;
        
        System.out.println("Vnesete kolku proizvodi ke stavite: ");
        n=input.nextInt();
        
            
        
        String imer = input.nextLine();
        int cenar = input.nextInt();

        
        pro1.dodadiProizvod(new Proizvod(imer, cenar));
        
        
        System.out.println("Ime-pr: "+pro1.proizvodi[0].getIme_proizvod()+" Cena= "+pro1.proizvodi[0].getCena());
    }
    
}
```

I can't enter The string "imer" or the int "cenar" on the variable "proizvodi" from the class Proizvod.

Comment: After you get this working, read this: [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Exception Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

```
String imer = input.next();// Use for String Input
input.nextLine();//Use for next line of input
int cenar = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps! I didn't knew that you can use only "input.next()". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an int in before you get to imer or cenar:

```
n=input.nextInt();
```

This line doesn't appear to be doing anything, either remove it, or put a number in before you put your imer or cenar values in.