# Reading the values for the graph from text file?

Tags: java, adjacency-matrix

I have a program which will take values from array.

```
 int graph[][] = new int[][] {{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                                {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                                {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                                {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                                {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
                               };
```

I have tried changing the inline input to text file input but i am getting type mismatch errors.

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("split_this.txt"));
String s = inFile.nextLine();
int numberOfVertices = Integer.parseInt(s);
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    s = inFile.nextLine();
    String[] triplet = s.split("[\\|]");
    String[][] tokens = new String[ triplet.length ][];
    for (int i = 0; i < triplet.length; i++){
        tokens[i] = triplet[i].split("[,]");
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < tokens.length; z++){
         for (int i = 0; i < tokens[z].length; i++){
            int graph[][] = tokens[z][i];
         }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is it me or is graph a int[] array and you are trying to store string values from the tokens array the graph integer array?

Comment: Please show example `split_this.txt` file

Comment: this is the content for that "split_this.txt" file
{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},                                
{2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
{0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
{6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                                {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have control on the file format then I would suggest to follow this one which is used in many of the competition problems:

```
row col
val11 val12 val13 ...
val21 val22 val23 ...
val31 val32 val33 ...
...
```

example for your case

```
5 5
0 2 0 6 0
2 0 3 8 5
0 3 0 0 7
6 8 0 0 9
0 5 7 9 0
```

After this, use Scanner to read the input:

```
Scanner scan - new Scanner(file);
int row = scan.nextInt();
int col = scan.nextInt();
int[][] graph = new int[row][col];
for(int r=0; r<row; r++) {
   for(int c=0; c<col; c++) {
      graph[r][c] = scan.nextInt();

  }
}
```

Comment: getting null pointer exception while compiling. 
Here is the scanner command: " Scanner scan = new Scanner("in.txt");" @CMPS

Comment: post the stack trace please

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at MST.main(MST.java:100)'

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143028/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexception