# Java Maze from a file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, error-handling, computer-science

i got a maze from a file i try to make this Write a class Exercise4 with a program that reads such a maze file into a two-dimensional boolean array. Then display the array on the console with one line for each row. Represent array elements using blank-symbols and #-symbols so that the console output has the same format as the maze file, see the example above.

```
    package assignmentce152;


    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
/**
 * Created by ak on 29/03/2017.
 */
public class Exercise4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Mazes();
    }
        private static char[][] maze = null;
        private static int rows = 0;
        private static int cols = 0;
        private static int xStart = 0;
        private static int yStart = 0;

        public static void Mazes() throws IOException {
            File mazefile = new File("C:/Users/IdeaProjects/Assignment152/data/maze21.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mazefile));

           Scanner lineOfFile = new Scanner(reader.readLine()); 

            rows = lineOfFile.nextInt(); //get the number of rows of the maze

            cols = lineOfFile.nextInt(); // get the number of columns of the maze
            maze = new char[rows][cols]; //create a char array of the proper size

            //For loops to iterate the rows and col to find the start/enterance of the maze as it pertains to the first char in the row
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                lineOfFile = new Scanner(reader.readLine());
                for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
                    char start = lineOfFile.next().charAt(0);
                    maze[x][y] = start;

                    //statement to set the starting coorinates for the maze
                    if (start == '.') {
                        xStart = x;
                        yStart = y;
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

how ever i got these ERROR what should i change ? Anything i think will be helpful

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at assignmentce152.Exercise4.Mazes(Exercise4.java:28)
at assignmentce152.Exercise4.main(Exercise4.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143028/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexception

Comment: Well to be honest i cant figure how to fix it in my own program. because is not very similar

Answer (score 0):

It seems your program tries to read two integers from the scanner and does not find two integers there.

Let me guess: the following line is wrong.

```
       Scanner lineOfFile = new Scanner(reader.readLine());
```

`readLine()` reads the first line of your file. From this line you create a scanner object that could be used for parsing the line. If, for instance, your two numbers are on the first *two* lines of your file, it will never get to them both and will throw an `InputMismatchException`.

Instead you can try discarding the `reader` and just creating your scanner as

```
       Scanner lineOfFile = new Scanner(mazefile);
```

This will allow your scanner to read the entire text file rather than only the first line.

If this doesn’t solve your problem, I believe you need to edit your question and add a sample of how your file looks.