# InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble

Tags: java

I am doing some small pratice using java language and stuck with these:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nhap {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n;
        n= sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(1.0/n);
    }
}
```

when I try to enter a number of type double . It shows me this error:

```
0.56
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at nhap.nhap.main(nhap.java:10)
```

I'm looking for some advice that help me solve this problem :)

Comment: You haven't shown your input, but it clearly doesn't contain something that can be read as a double.

Comment: thanks, I updated my question

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143523/4592448 =)

Comment: Are you using the correct `Locale`? Try inputting `0,56` or changing the locale to something like `new Scanner().useLocale(java.util.Locale.US)`

Comment: thanks guys 0,56 worked for me :)